# fopen alternative for FPDF (PHP)

Tags: php, fopen, fpdf

I am using FPDF to extract info from a PNG file.  Unfortunately, the server has fopen disabled.  Can anyone recommend a good way of getting around this?  Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

```
function _parsepng($file)
{
    // Extract info from a PNG file
    $f = fopen($file,'rb');
    if(!$f)
        $this->Error('Can\'t open image file: '.$file);
    $info = $this->_parsepngstream($f,$file);
    fclose($f);
    return $info;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ended up using a cURL workaround.  Thanks everyone for the input!

```
function _parsepng($file)
{
    $ch = curl_init($file);
    $fp = fopen('/tmp/myfile.png', 'wb');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    $image_data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    // Extract info from a PNG file
    $f = fopen('/tmp/myfile.png','rb');
    if(!$f)
        $this->Error('Can\'t open image file: '.$file);
    $info = $this->_parsepngstream($f,$file);
    fclose($f);
    return $info;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [curl](http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php) but usually if your hosting company disables one they also disable the other.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response!  I was told cURL will work fine, but I've never worked with it before.  Any good tips or recommendations on going about it?

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know if it can work :-)

but you may try with fsockopen

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php

file:// can be used as protocol

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I've tried fsockopen already and ran into the same problem.

Comment: so I think it's better having some info about _parsepngstream implementation. reading the code you need a file pointer resource to pass as parameter, maybe there is a way to avoid it